# Mac - fatal error: 'linux/tipc.h' file not found

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, tipc

When running a "make" command, fatal errors are returned due to missing linux headers.

Example:
fatal error:  file not found

Comment: Where you go next depends on what you want to do next. (And/or vise versa) TIPC is a cluster-level comm protocol. Are you planning to build a cluster of Macs? Do you want to use other (non-TIPC) options of the software you are building?

Comment: What are you trying to build?

Comment: The program you are trying to build may simply not support Mac, in which case you probably proceed by choosing either a different program or a different machine to build and run it on (a Linux machine).  On the other hand, possibly it supports Mac, but you have to do something to configure the build appropriately.  If so, the program documentation should tell you about that.

Comment: I suppose my question can be simplified.  Is there a way to get linux-headers for mac?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You setup the cross-compilation environment in which you may be able to use Linux kernel headers and compile **for Linux** on Mac. But compiling **for Mac** with Linux kernel headers is non-sense.

Comment: @TruBlu yes you can get the Linux headers on a Mac. Clone the Linux git repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) virtual machine (VM) using [VirtualBox](https://www.oracle.com/virtualization/technologies/vm/downloads/virtualbox-downloads.html).

- Installed required software
- Mounted shared folder

The make commands ran successfully in the vm.